# cfqueryparam questions/help

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sql-injection, cfqueryparam

Via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599465/coldfusion-dealing-with-null-values-in-date-field) I've been told to start using cfqueryparam for my data, to prevent SQL injection attacks.

How do I use it for my forms? Right now I've been going over Ben Forta's book, Vol 1 and been passing data to my form, then to a form processor that calls a CFC. The CFC takes them in as a `cfargument` then injects that into the database with any type="x" validation.

Io use the `cfqueryparam`, I use that on the query itself and not even declare `cfargument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a CFC, but remember that string data passed as a function argument will still need `<cfqueryparam>`. Here is an example:

```
<cffunction name="saveData" access="public" returntype="void" output="false"> 
 <cfargument name="formVar" type="string" required="true" />

 <cfquery name="LOCAL.qSave" datasource="myDSN">

  insert into myTable (col1)
  values (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.formVar#" />)

 </cfquery>

</cffunction>
```

The important habit to get into is to always use `<cfqueryparam>`, even in CFCs.

Here is some more [info on those edge-cases](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/677.cfm) where you might find it hard to use `<cfqueryparam>`.

Hope that helps!